# É possível obter o nome e valor de todas as sessions por javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, session

Estou criando várias sessions, e gostaria de obter o nome e valor de todas por JavaScript.

Ao criar duas Sessions em Asp.Net MVC, por exemplo:

```
Session["usuario"] = "user";
Session["tipo"] = "comum";
```

Gostaria de obter as duas sessions na View, sem saber o nome.
Exemplo:

```
<script>
  var sessions = getTodasAsSessions(); // Existe alguma função desse tipo?
  for(var i = 0; i < sessions.length; i++){
      alert("Nome da Session: " + sessions[i].Name + " Valor: " + sessions[i].Value);
  }
</script>
```

Isso é possível?

Comment: Acredito que não porque abriria brecha de segurança, mas qual a finalidade disso?

Comment: Você quer pegar as sessões no front-end?

Comment: Exato GuilhermeNascimento.

Comment: MaiconCarraro, estou fazendo um projeto onde dependendo do tipo do usuário crio várias sessions diferentes, e tenho que recuperá-las na View. Realmente faz sentido a questão da segurança, mas a criptografia não resolveria?

Comment: Dado que você conseguiu implementar a `getTodasAsSessions()`, você vai fazer o quê com isso? Você vai usar isso pra renderizar seletivamente as coisas no front-end, pra adiantar os erros de permissão, …?

Comment: Não tenho implementado ainda `getTodasAsSessions`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você não consegue aceder a uma variável de sessão do servidor no lado do cliente.

Agora podes é "brincar" um bocado com o teu código para conseguires obter os valores das sessões no lado cliente.
Vou-te dar uma pequena ideia daquilo que podes fazer:

1. Criar um hidden field no HTML e atribuir o valor da sessão ao hidden field no lado do servidor.

   `hfSessionValue.Value = HttpContext.Current.Session("NomeDaSession").ToString`
2. Criar função JavaScript para ir buscar o valor do hidden field:

   `function getSessionValue() {
       return documento.getElementById("hfSessionValue").value;
   }`